# Minimum value of given expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

What is the minimum value of the $$ \frac {x^2 + x + 1 }  {x^2 - x + 1 } \ ?$$

I have solved by equating it to m and then discriminant greater than or equal to zero and got the answer, but can algebraic manipulation is possible

Comment: You can find the minimum value of a function by setting the derivative of the function to zero and solving the resulting expression for $x$.

Comment: Also, you can simplify slightly by noting that $\frac {x^2 + x + 1 }  {x^2 - x + 1 } = 1+\frac {2x }  {x^2 - x + 1 }$.

Comment: @Daryl: The question is labeled [algebra-precalculus], which would seem to mean we should check for non-calculus solutions.

Answer (score 5):

let y=$\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x+1}$

=>$x^2(y-1)-x(y+1)+(y-1)=0$

As x is real, the discriminant= $(y+1)^2-4(y-1)^2≥0$

=>$(y-3)(y-\frac{1}{3})≤0$

=>$\frac{1}{3}≤y≤3$

Comment: +1 Cute technique; must have missed that with my 'new maths'...

Comment: To get from $1/3\leq y \leq 3$ to asserting that the minimum value is actually $1/3$, you need to demonstrate that $1/3$ is actually a possible value for $y$.  In other words, you must show that there is a value of $x$ that gives this.  Of course, there is, it's $x=-1$, but you really need to give this as part of your solution.

Comment: +2n+1 :D This technique is so easy to understand and suitable <3

Answer (score 2):

Here is an 'algebra solution':

$\frac {x^2 + x + 1 }  {x^2 - x + 1 } = \frac{(x+1)^2-(x+1)+1}{(x+1)^2-3(x+1)+3} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \frac{(x+1)^2}{x^2-x+1} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{3} \frac{(x+1)^2}{(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}$.

Since the last term is greater than zero when $x\neq -1$, we see that the minimum is

> $\frac{1}{3}$.

Of course, this is cheating since I know the answer from J.D.'s solution and this suggests the way to expand the expression.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Take the derivative w.r.t $x$ and equate it with zero, you get:
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \frac {x^2 + x + 1 }  {x^2 - x + 1 } = - \frac {2(x^2 - 1)}  {(x^2 - x + 1)^2} = 0.$$
So $x = \pm 1$ at the extrema. Test both for minimum.

Edit: [this tutorial page](http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/extrema/) might be helpful.

Comment: But again, this is not algebra as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For $x\geq0$ we have $$\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x+1}=1+\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}\geq1.$$
For $x<0$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{x^2+x+1}{x^2-x+1}=1+\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}=1+\frac{2}{x+\frac{1}{x}-1}=$$
$$=1-\frac{2}{-x+\frac{1}{-x}+1}\geq1-\frac{2}{2\sqrt{-x\cdot\frac{1}{-x}}+1}=\frac{1}{3}.$$
The equality occurs for $-x=\frac{1}{-x}$ or for $x=-1,$ which says that we got a minimal value.

By the same way we can get a maximal value if you want.