# Finding minimum given constraint

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I would like to solve the following problem.

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $a+2b=1$. Find the minimum value of $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}$.

Using AM-GM, I get $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right) \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{ab}}$$

I tried using the constraint to rewrite as $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-2b}+\frac{1}{b}\right) \geq \sqrt{\frac{1}{(1-2b)b}}$$

However, I don't see how this would help me as the right side of the inequality does not reduce to a constant.

I have seen AM-GM examples utilizing creative tricks to create a constant and I wonder if there is one for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Replace $a$ with $1-2b$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174905/minimum-value-of-given-expression

Answer (score 1):

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$(a+2b)\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}\right) \ge (1+\sqrt2)^2 \implies \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} \ge (1+\sqrt2)^2.$$
The equality holds when $$a = \sqrt{2}b \implies a=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}, b=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: So you have a lower bound. Unless you show it can be actually achieved for allowable $a,b$, you cannot claim it’s a minimum. In this case you need to show $a+2b=1, a^2=2b^2$ has a non negative solution.

Comment: @Macavity The lower bound is achieved when $$a=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}, b=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

If the application of trigonometry is allowed,

WLOG. $a=\sin^2t,2b=\cos^2t$

Now use $$\dfrac{x\tan^2t+y\cot^2t}2\ge\sqrt{x\tan^2t\cdot y\cot^2t}=?$$ for $x,y>0$