# How to find the range of $y=\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$ without using derivative?

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

The only thing I know with this equation is $y=\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=x+1-\frac{2x}{x+1}$.

Maybe it can be solved by using inequality.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174905/minimum-value-of-given-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not exist.

Try $x\rightarrow-1^-$.

For $x>-1$ by AM-GM  we obtain:
$$\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}=\frac{x^2-1+2}{x+1}=x-1+\frac{2}{x+1}=$$
$$=x+1+\frac{2}{x+1}-2\geq2\sqrt{(x+1)\cdot\frac{2}{x+1}}-2=2\sqrt2-2.$$
The equality occurs for $x+1=\frac{2}{x+1},$ which says that we got a minimal value and the local minimal value.

Thus, the range for $x>0$ it's $[2\sqrt2-2,+\infty).$

For $x<-1$ we can get the range by the similar way.

Comment: Sorry, I use the misunderstood word. It's a local maximum.

Comment: @yuanming luo I added something. See now.

Comment: Thanks, I think I can apply the same tech for the negative side.

Comment: @yuanming luo Yes, of course!

Comment: How can I know the result found by AM-GM is the lower bound at the first quadrant?

Comment: @user604720 We get lower bound occurs in the first quadrant in the case $x>-1$.  We can use AM-GM in this case because $x+1>0$. Actually, for $x+1>0$ we can get a minimum point in another quadrant for another similar function.

Comment: Emmmmm I mean whether $2\sqrt2 -2 $ is the lowest bound at first quadrant. How do we show that there is no more bound lower than that.

Comment: @yuanming luo Because I proved that for all $x>-1$ we have $y\geq2\sqrt2-2.$

Comment: For $y=2$, you can also show that $\forall x \gt -1, y \gt 2\sqrt2 -2$. It's not enough to show that it is the infimum.

Answer (score 2):

The equation $$y={x^2+1\over x+1}=a\to x^2-ax-(a-1)=0$$for $x\ne -1$ has a real root if and only if $$\Delta\ge0 \iff a^2+4a-4\ge 0\iff a\ge 2\sqrt 2-2\text{ or }a\le -2\sqrt 2-2$$in that case, the root is $\ne -1$ automatically (if not, it leads to the impossible non-equality $a-1=a+1$), Therefore the range simply is $$(-\infty,-2\sqrt 2-2]\ \bigcup \ [2\sqrt 2-2,\infty)$$

Answer (score 1):

Out of the given answers, one simple way is to get the $x$ in terms of $y$ and solve it :)

$y=\frac{x^2+1}{x+1}$
$$\Rightarrow yx + y = x^2 +1 \Rightarrow -x^2 + yx +(y-1)=0 \Rightarrow x = \frac{-y \pm\sqrt{y^2 + 4(y-1)}}{-2} \Rightarrow \frac{-y \pm \sqrt{(y-(-2-\sqrt5))(y - (\sqrt5-2))}}{-2}$$

The Lowest Value so will be obtained will be when the value under square root = 0, then in that case

$$ = \frac{-\sqrt5+2}{-2}$$

Now plug that value in the expression for $x$ Gives the minimal value of $y$:

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{x^2+1}{x+1} = -\infty,$$

the minimum does not exist.

Comment: sorry, I use the misunderstood word. It's a local maximum.