# Finding the min and max of a rational function.

Tags: derivatives, maxima-minima

I have a function $f(x) = \frac{x^2-1}{x^4+1}$

The x-coordintes of the maximum are found by the derivative.

$f'(x) =\frac{(x^4+1)(2x)-(x^2-1)(4x^3)}{x^4+1}$

Setting it equal to zero and solving for x gives:

$x^4-2x^2-1=0$ which solves to $x=\pm 1$

However, there is a minimum when $x=0$.

[image]

From my picture i only got the x-coordinates for the maximums, why didn't i get the x-coordinate for the minimum as well?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174905/minimum-value-of-given-expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you divided both sides by $x$, excluding the solution $x = 0$.

$$f'(x) =\frac{(x^4+1)(2x)-(x^2-1)(4x^3)}{x^4+1}$$

$$f'(x) = 0 \iff (x^4+1)(2x)-(x^2-1)(4x^3) = 0$$

$$2x^5+2x-4x^5+4x^3 = 0 \iff -2x^5+4x^3+2x = 0$$

Here, $x = 0$ is clearly a solution. After this, you can simplify both sides and continue as you did. (Alternatively, you can factor $x$ from the start, which yields $x = 0$ as a solution.)

Comment: ah thank you, i should've been more careful and i should've noticed that